# Creating a job that outputs multiple files instead of appending to one file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have a table `dbo.Options`. This table is the same in two different databases - `Database1` and `SysAdmin`.

In `Database1`, people can come and change information on that table. so I have created a job that runs a script comparing both tables and if there is a difference, it outputs the difference to a file.

When the job runs again, it overwrites whatever is on the old file.
now my issue is i want a new file to be created every time that job runs. i cannot used the append option because that just writes to the same file instead of creating a new file.

I would prefer to have a script I can add to my already existing script that will create these multiple files. Any other suggestion will be helpful too.

TIA

Comment: You would at the very least, need to post the code in your job that does this.

Comment: Okay Nick. Let me do that.